# JAVA: Finding Values in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Set numMatches to the number of elements in userValues (having NUM_VALS elements) that equal matchValue. Ex: If matchValue = 2 and userValues = {2, 2, 1, 2}, then numMatches = 3.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindMatchValue {
public static void main (String [] args) {
   final int NUM_VALS = 4;
   int[] userValues = new int[NUM_VALS];
   int i = 0;
   int matchValue = 0;
   int numMatches = -99; // Assign numMatches with 0 before your for loop

  userValues[0] = 2;
  userValues[1] = 2;
  userValues[2] = 1;
  userValues[3] = 2;

  matchValue = 2;

  **/* Your solution goes here  */**

  numMatches = 0;

 for(i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; ++i) {
    if(userValues[i] == matchValue)
       numMatches = i;
 }        
  System.out.println("matchValue: " + matchValue + ", numMatches: " +     numMatches);

  return;
  }
}
```

My solution has mistakes that I can't figure out.

Testing matchValue = 0,

userValues = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

Expected value:  5

Your value:  4 <<< This is where I'm going wrong.

Comment: and your question are... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; ++i) {
   if(userValues[i] == matchValue) {
      //numMatches = i;   //WRONG
      numMatches++;     //Correct
   }
}
```

This block is incorrect, you are assigning numMatches to the index value of the array rather, it should have been that if there's a match increment values of numMatches by 1.

Answer (score 1):

`numMatches++` this is what you need to do in the for loop instead of `numMatches = i;`

Answer (score 1):

```
   numMatches = 0; //initialize numMatches to 0
   for (i = 0; i < userValues.length; ++i) {
     if(userValues[i] == matchValue){
        matchValue = userValues[i]; //reassign numValue to the current array value
         numMatches +=1;//increment numValue by 1
        }
  }
```